# How to apply regex substitutions to Pandas Series containing string, lists?

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I'd like to find a way to apply a regular expression substitution to every element of a Pandas Series where the series may contain strings, lists, or dicts.

The objective would be to replace instances of text matching a specified pattern in a DataFrame column before that column is saved into Google BigQuery.

I can achieve this no problem where the Series contains only string values, e.g.:

`['string 1', 'string 2', 'string 3']`

However there may be instances in which the Series contains 'nested' data - in which each item in the series is a list containing *n* dicts:

```
[ 
    [ 
         { 'val1':'string 1', 'val2':'string 2' },
         { 'val1':'string 3', 'val2':'string 4' }
    ],
    [
         { 'val1':'string 1', 'val2':'string 6' }
    ]
]
```

Ideally, I'd be able to create a function which can perform the substitution for each element in a series regardless of whether the series contains 'nested' values or not.

As an example, and using the sample values above, it may be that the function would be used to replace instances of 'string 1' with 'abcdef' - with the following outputs:

`['abcdef', 'string 2', 'string 3']`

```
[ 
    [ 
         { 'val1':'abcdef', 'val2':'string 2' },
         { 'val1':'string 3', 'val2':'string 4' }
    ],
    [
         { 'val1':'abcdef', 'val2':'string 6' }
    ]
]
```

I had thought that it might be possible to do something similar to the below:

```
def regex_replace_in_series(series_item, regex_pattern, replacement):
    if type(series_item) == 'str':
        return re.sub(regex_pattern, replacement, series_item)
    elif type(series_item) == 'list': 
        return [regex_replace_in_series(item, regex_pattern, replacement) for item in series_item]
    elif type(series_item) == 'dict':
        for key in series_item:
            series_item[key] = regex_replace_in_series(series_item[key], regex_pattern, replacement)
        return series_item
    else: 
        return series_item

my_series.apply(regex_replace_in_series, args=[some_pattern, some_replacement])
```

But I imagine that this would be a relatively slow/error prone way of achieving the desired outcome.

Is there a better way?

Thanks

Comment: Not a direct answer, but if you're using pandas to hold nested structures in which you want to perform regex substitutions, then you're not using pandas for its designed purpose. You could use pure python lists and have a better efficiency…

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is:

- transform your dataframe to csv
- replace the strings you need by exploiting string context
- get back your dataframe

Here's a quick snippet that does replace strings within dictionaries by taking into account keys as a context:

```
import io
import re

# transforming dataframe to csv string
string_df = df.to_csv(index=False)[1:]

# applying replacements on dicts
strings_to_replace_in_dict = [('val1', 'string 1', 'abcdef')]
for key, value, replacement in strings_to_replace_in_dict:
    string_df = re.sub(r"('"+key+"': ')"+value, r"\1"+replacement, string_df)

# transforming csv string back to dataframe
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(string_df))
```

You can handle list replacements in an analogous way.

Does this answer provide help for your problem?

Comment: Thanks for the response! I had considered a similar approach using JSON, but was concerned that it may be possible for some regex patterns to invalidate the CSV/JSON format (e.g. if the pattern accidentally removed delimiters). Also, ideally, the code would not be depended on the presence of keys, and would therefore also work when applied to a series containing simple strings only

Comment: Agree with you that this is a risky approach, yet when I was writing it, thought that if you handle it with caution, it may be the most efficient solution wrt handling dataframes (which is feasible here anyways, but heavier). For what concerns the snippet I've written here, the delimiters are safe inside the group delimited by parentheses, which is carried using the backreference `\1`, no delimiter should be lost. For the series case, can you provide an example in your question? Or in general, can you provide corner cases from your data? @j_marvin

Answer (score 0):

I have determined an alternative approach to the management of nested data is more appropriate when using Python/Pandas.

This is based on:

- Complexity of performing some operations (e.g. regex replace) on Pandas Series containing non-string types (as per the subject of this question)
- Issues when attempting to create 'deep' copies of 'nested' columns in Pandas (as per [pd.df.copy](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html))

I've concluded that data processing should be performed *before* the nesting of data prior saving data into BigQuery:

- **Incorrect**: Source -> Nest -> Process -> Store
- **Correct**: Source -> Process -> Nest -> Store

It appears as though it may be possible to create the required nested structures once all data processing is complete using a combination of Pandas methods - including groupby() and agg().

Prior to that point I can perform all processing on Series containing str values only.

Thanks to all those who took time to respond - much appreciated